# How to get sum of colored cells in Excel

Tags: excel

Good day,
I have a task to get a sum of cells with a given Background cell color.
as shown in this image:
Table A - is the dataset and table B should be the goal, such that is Paul has 5 in cell E2 and 2 in cell H2 it sums in Table B shows that Paul has a total of 7 based on the color RED.
Thanks
[sum of colored cells](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ek726.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uOKrQ.png)

Comment: What criteria are used to determine a cell's color?

Comment: http://www.cpearson.com/excel/colors.aspx

Answer (score 0):

You will need to use VBA for this. [Here](https://www.ablebits.com/office-addins-blog/2013/12/12/count-sum-by-color-excel/comment-page-2/#:%7E:text=Simply%20enter%20either%20formula%20in,same%20color%20in%20your%20workbook.) is an explanation of how to do what you are looking for.

Alternatively, if the color scheme is a result of conditional formatting you could look into whether you can use the same formula that produces the colors within a sumif function.